# Multiple Texture Support BGE

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine

Is there a way to add multiple functional textures in the Game Engine. What I'd like to do is have one texture that maps the Diff and another that maps the Spec and Bump.

It always seems to override to one or the other when I have multiples placed. Is that a limitation I have to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in GLSL mode:
[image]

Make sure each texture only affects the channels you want:
[image]

In this example I want this image to influence the specular channel, so I have unticked the Diffuse Color box and ticked the Specular Intensity checkbox.

Comment: This did it. I wasn't in GLSL mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do so, just add all the textures to your object. Under textures settings at the bottom you should be able to select whether you want the texture be used for color, displacement, ... just adjust the values, eg for Bump Map turn down "color" from 1, which is default, to 0 and incrase displacement to 1 instead.

Comment: So, I've tried this, and it just picks the top texture to use as a setting for everything.

Comment: You mean the color of the top texture "dominates"? Turn the color value of this texture to zero.

Comment: Under "Influence", and you might only check the option you need :)